# Finding the proportion in Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

The weather on any given day in a particular city can be sunny, cloudy, or rainy. It has been observed to be predictable largely on the basis of the weather on the previous day.

Observations have shown that:

if it is **sunny on one day**, it will be **sunny the next** day $\frac25$ of the time, and be **cloudy the next** day $\frac25$ of the time.

If it is **cloudy on one day**, it will be **sunny the next** day $\frac25$ of the time, and be **cloudy the next day** $\frac35$ of the time.

If it is **rainy on one day**, it will be sunny the next day $\frac35$ of the time, and be **cloudy the next** day $\frac15$ of the time.

Using 'sunny', 'cloudy', and 'rainy' (in that order) as the states in a system, set up the transition matrix for a Markov chain to describe this system.

Find the proportion of days that have each type of weather in the long run.

I have found the matrix, I can't seem to find the proportions for sunny, cloudy and rainy

$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac25&\frac25&\frac35\\
\frac25&\frac35&\frac15\\
\frac15&0&\frac15\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that usually the probability $p_{i,j}$ in transition matrix denotes the probability to move from state $i$ to state $j$. And also the transition matrix should be stochastic: $\sum_j p_{i,j}=1$ for all $i$. Therefore your matrix should looks like:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\frac25&\frac25&\frac15\\
\frac25&\frac35&0\\
\frac35&\frac15&\frac15\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And then the vector of stationary probabilities (long-term proportions of states) will be the solution of the system of equations: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}P_s&P_c&P_r\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\frac25&\frac25&\frac15\\
\frac25&\frac35&0\\
\frac35&\frac15&\frac15\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}P_s&P_c&P_r\end{bmatrix}
$$
In your matrix everything is the other way around: $p_{i,j}$ is the probability to move from $j$ to $i$. So, it is transposed. If you prefer to use your martix anyway, you should multiply matrix to a vector, not vice versa: 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\frac25&\frac25&\frac35\\
\frac25&\frac35&\frac15\\
\frac15&0&\frac15\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}P_s\\P_c\\P_r\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}P_s\\P_c\\P_r\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Both cases the solution is $P_s=\frac8{19}$, $P_c=\frac9{19}$, $P_r=\frac2{19}$.